# What happened to this answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

[Surgical strikes by India](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39042/surgical-strikes-by-india)

Google cache shows that this question had two answers.

[image]

What happened to this answer?

Is it deleted by SE admin?

Why?

Comment: It could be undeleted, but only by a moderator. Since a moderator was disputing the content, it seems unlikely that they would do that

Comment: I haven't been involved with that question, but looking at the answer advocated here, it's the usual one-sided, nationalistic flag waving. Intersting that the account aksing this meta question also made a dissapearing act...

Answer (score 12):

The user that posted the answer either deleted their account themselves, or had their account deleted or destroyed. When an account is deleted, all contributions with a negative score are also deleted (with some exceptions, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)). When an account is destroyed, all contributions are deleted regardless of score.

This post had a score of -1, so was deleted automatically by the Community user when the poster's account was removed.

Comment: the *all negative-score posts deleted* is explained further [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/303080)

Comment: So _that's_ what it means that Community deleted a post. Good to know.

Comment: @Bobson posts deleted by spam & rude flags will also be shown as "deleted by Community" too.